# git-http-backend returns error 502

Tags: git, gitolite, gitweb

I'm running gitweb and gitolite on my server: http://git.jshawl.com/

I'm having trouble setting up the `git-http-backend` to allow anonymous cloning.

Here's what my vhosts file (`/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`) looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/Users/git/repositories"
ServerName git.jshawl.com
 <Directory "/Users/git/repositories">
    Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
</Directory>

<LocationMatch "^/.*/git-receive-pack$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    Require group committers
</LocationMatch

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /Users/git/repositories
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/(.*/(HEAD | \
        info/refs | \
            objects/(info/[^/]+ | \
                [0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38} | \
                    pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx)) | \
            git-(upload|receive)-pack))$" \
    /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/$1

ScriptAlias / /Users/git/repositories/gitweb.cgi/
```

`

I followed the directions here: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-http-backend.html, but am consistently confronted with that 502 error.

My apache error log says: `[Fri Aug 24 19:29:32 2012] [error] [client 198.228.200.148] client denied by server configuration: /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend`

Also, adding all of this has taken down my gitweb installation (which used to be at http://git.jshawl.com)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [another approach in this `httpd.conf`](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-84) which works well for cloning/pushing/pulling, but **it doesn't call gitweb.cgi**:

GitWeb is for browsing, not for cloning

(small extract, removing Auth details, and SSL details)

```
# GitHttp on @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
Listen @PORT_HTTP_HGIT@
<VirtualHost @FQN@:@PORT_HTTP_HGIT@>
  ServerName @FQN@
  ServerAlias @HOSTNAME@
  SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT @H@/repositories
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
  SetEnv GITOLITE_HTTP_HOME @H@
  ScriptAlias /hgit/ @H@/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell/
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "@H@/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"
  <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
  </FilesMatch>
  <Location /hgit>
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

In other words:

- `git-http-backend` is referenced by the variable  `GIT_HTTP_BACKEND`, but **you won't need it if you are using Gitolite V3**.
- **[`gitolite-shell`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell)** is called when you are using `/hgit/` in your cloning address: theat GitoliteV3 script will check if you have the right to clone the repo, and if yes, will call the commands behind the script `git-http-backend`: '`git-receive-pack`' (for push) or '`git-upload-pack`' (for clone/pull/fetch), straight from the git source itself [`http-backend.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/http-backend.c#L518-533).

So:

```
git clone https://yourServer/hgit/yourRepo
```

Will call gitolite, which will call '`git-receive-pack`' or '`git-upload-pack`'.
It will first analyze the http request by calling [`sub http_simulate_ssh_connection()`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/src/gitolite-shell#L200-L221)

```
sub http_simulate_ssh_connection {
    # these patterns indicate normal git usage; see "services[]" in
    # http-backend.c for how I got that. Also note that "info" is overloaded;
    # git uses "info/refs...", while gitolite uses "info" or "info?...". So
    # there's a "/" after info in the list below
    if ( $ENV{PATH_INFO} =~ m(^/(.*)/(HEAD$|info/refs$|objects/|git-(?:upload|receive)-pack$)) ) {
        my $repo = $1;
        my $verb = ( $ENV{REQUEST_URI} =~ /git-receive-pack/ ) ? 'git-receive-pack' : 'git-upload-pack';
        $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} = "$verb '$repo'";
    } else {
        # this is one of our custom commands; could be anything really,
        # because of the adc feature
        my ($verb) = ( $ENV{PATH_INFO} =~ m(^/(\S+)) );
        my $args = $ENV{QUERY_STRING};
        $args =~ s/\+/ /g;
        $args =~ s/%([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
        $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} = $verb;
        $ENV{SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND} .= " $args" if $args;
        http_print_headers(); # in preparation for the eventual output!
    }
    $ENV{SSH_CONNECTION} = "$ENV{REMOTE_ADDR} $ENV{REMOTE_PORT} $ENV{SERVER_ADDR} $ENV{SERVER_PORT}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now. Pardon my ignorance, but are the things wrapped in "@" just placeholders for what I should be filling

Comment: @jessh yes those are to be replaced with your own values. I have everything (git repos, `git-http-backend`, `gitolite-shell`) under'`@H@`'. But in your case, those could be three separate paths.

Comment: perfect! What about your `hgit` by ScriptMatchAlias? That entire line has me a bit confused, actually. Where is the default gitolite-shell?

Comment: @jessh I have updated my answer to detail precisely how a clone/push/pull/fetch over http works, when you have Gitolite in the middle (to take care of the authorization part, before calling git itself)