# Need a password prompt for GITOLITE

Tags: git, ssh, passwords, gitolite, required

We would like to use gitolite after reading the documentation for the better access management.

We need a special requirement of where users should get prompted for password. I dont know if it is feasible but we require it as there is a chance of pushing their unwanted changes without any prompt. At least user will have a chance of aborting the changes while pushing during password prompt and also have option to abort if he/she is trying to pull some other branch code mistakenly on a current branch.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the Gitolite documentation, [Gitolite is an **authorization layer**, *not* an authentication layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html).

See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318715/how-do-programs-like-gitolite-work/13320256#13320256)": Gitolite takes advantage of any id that you will pass, either [by ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906633/users-are-asked-for-password-while-using-gitolite/10909791#10909791) or http.
For http example, see "[`git-http-backend` returns error 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117942/git-http-backend-returns-error-502/12118131#12118131)".

So if you setup:

- an ssh access with a password-protected private ssh key (and no ssh-agent), or
- an https access, with authentication required (`Require valid-user`),

then your users will have to enter a password for each of their git operations (push/pull/clone) interacting with the remotes repos behind your `ssh` daemon of `httpd` process.