# I want to restrict public access on Gitolite

Tags: git, gitolite

I'm using Gitolite for version control.

I want to restrict public access on Gitolite.

When anonymous tried to access Git repository, I want to force a prompt for authentication.

How can I restrict public access on Gitolite?

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like gitolite can use ssh authentication: http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh/ Have you tried setting that up?

Comment: What have you tried already? Are you serving git using http(s) or ssh or both? Point to the steps in the online documentation that you have followed and what is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of gitolite *is* to restrict public access, so you are on the right track.
See "[How do programs like gitolite work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)".

If your Gitolite server offers only SSH, then any anonymous access will have to follow the directives of your [Gitolite conf file](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/).
Unless that configuration file in your gitolite-admin repo references the [special group `@all`](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf/#special-group-all), then an anonymous access would be denied.

If your Gitolite server offers an HTTPS listener, then the authentication burden lies with that HTTPS server: see "[Need a password prompt for GITOLITE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13689181/6309)": gitolite is an authorization service, not an *authentication* one.